# ModelMultipleChoisefield con objetos unicos de cada usuario Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

tengo un modelo usuario que tiene un campo ManytoMany() a otro objeto:

```
class PrivateWallet(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    private_wallets = models.ManyToManyField(PrivateWallet, blank=True)
```

y quiero crear un formulario en el que el usuario pueda eliminar ese PrivateWallet:

```
class DeletePrivateWalletForm(forms.Form):
    wallets = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=¿?.objects.all(),to_field_name="name",required=True)
```

Me gustaría saber qué tengo que poner en lugar de **¿?** del formulario para que al usuario se le muestre solo los privateWallets creados por él.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que quieres hacer lo mejor es modificar el campo desde el constructor de la clase, pasándole al constructor como argumento el usuario o queryset a partir del cual se van a mostrar los wallets. De esta forma:

```
class DeletePrivateWalletForm(forms.Form):
    wallets = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=PrivateWallet.objects.none(), to_field_name="name", required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.get('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['wallets'].queryset = user.private_wallets.all()
```

Y en tu vista, cuando vayas a crear la instancia del formulario, recuerda pasarle el usuario, por darte un ejemplo:

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeletePrivateWalletForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        form = DeletePrivateWalletForm(user=request.user)
    return render...
```